# Solving a Ricatti type equation

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, numerical-linear-algebra

Could anyone help me solve this equation? Let $n,m,l$ be positive integers such that $n \ge m$ and $l>m$, but there is no such constraint between $l$ and $n$.

We have two known matrices $Q_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $Q_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}$.

The unknowns are $S \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ symmetric, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times l}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{l \times l}$ symmetric. The equations are
$$\begin{align}
S^2 + B C B^T &= Q_1^T Q_1 \\
B^T B + C &= Q_2^T Q_2 \\
S B + B C &= Q_1^T Q_2
\end{align}
$$

One can write it in a structured way
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
S & B \\ B^T & I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\ 0 & C
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
S & B \\ B^T & I
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_1^T \\ Q_2^T
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_1 & Q_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have a suspicion that this is a type of Ricatti equation. If it helps I have come to this set of equations by trying to solve the larger system
$$
\begin{align}
P_1 S + P_2 B^T &= Q_1\\
P_1 B + P_2 &= Q_2\\
P_1^T P_1 &= I\\
P_1^T P_2 &= 0,
\end{align}
$$
where $P_1$, $P_2$ are additional unknowns, which have the same size as $Q_1$, $Q_2$, respectively.

Comment: Could you please detail more where this is coming from. That is, could you please add details on the last system you are mentioning. I suspect that it may be easier to solve. In particular, what are the dimensions of the unknown matrices.

Comment: It is an optimisation problem: find matrices $P_1$, $P_2$  that are the closest to $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ in the Frobenius norm such that the constraints $P_1^T P_1 = I$ and $P_1^T P_2 =0$ hold. Here $S$ and $B$ are related to Lagrange multipliers and $C$ is simply $P_2^T P_2$, which we don't care about.

Comment: This problem is also equivalent to finding $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ ($m<n$) such that $X Y + Q Q^T P = B$ and $X^T X = I$, where $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times l}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ are given.